# How can I resolve htaccess causing social media bots to see 404 response even though the page displays correctly?

Tags: htaccess, php

I use the below htaccess code which appears to function correctly to rewrite URLS, however when a page is shared to social networks or scanned by bots like AHREFs, they all return 404 yet the pages at the site display correctly, and when I print http_response_code() on any page, the response value is 200.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$  $1/ [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**The long URL being rewritten**

```
index.php?component=posts&view=post&category=15-the-blog&post=31-how-blog-well&menuid=25-the-blog
```

**The rewritten URL**

```
/the-blog/how-to-blog-well
```

**The PHP functions that processes the URLS**

```
/* 
Process URLs as sent from links, before converted to SEF to 
retrieve $_GET[] values for use in DB queries and 
other instructions 
*/

function getNonSEF() 
{
    $path = pathinfo(currenturl());
    $filename = $path['filename'];
    $dirnames = explode('/', $path['dirname']);
    preg_match('#[^\/]+$#i', $path['dirname'], $match);


    // product detail and post view
    if( $path['dirname'].'/' == ROOT_URL ) 
    {
        $postid = posts()->where('alias', getCurrentFilename())->value('id');
        $cat_id = categories()->where('alias', getCurrentFilename())->value('id');

        $groupval = getDbo('mod_cmse_products')->select('group_id', 'group_alias')->where('group_alias', $filename)->get()[0];

        if( !empty($postid) ) {
            $queryurl = parse_url(menus()->where([['type', 3], ['src_id', $postid]])->value('url'))['query'];
        }else
        if( !empty($cat_id) ) {
            $url = menus()->where([['src_id', $cat_id], ['type', 2]])->value('url');
            if( !empty($url) ) {
                $queryurl = parse_url($url)['query'];
            }else{
                // category has no menu item
                $queryurl = 'component=posts&view=category&category='.$cat_id.'-'.getCurrentFilename();
            }
        }else
        // product category
        if( $filename == $groupval->group_alias ) {
            $queryurl = 'component=products&view=productgroup&gid='.$groupval->group_id.'-'.$groupval->group_alias;
        //}else
            //index.php?component=products&view=productgroups&menuid=25-all-services
        //if( in_array($filename, menus()->where('type', 5)->pluck('alias')) ) {
        //  $queryurl = parse_url(menus()->where('alias', getCurrentFilename())->value('url'))['query'];
        }else{
            $queryurl = parse_url(menus()->where('alias', getCurrentFilename())->value('url'))['query'];
        }

    }else

    {
        // if view is post and has category alias in url but does not have an assigned menu
        $postval = posts()->select('id', 'catid', 'alias')->where('alias', $filename)->get()[0];

        $prodval = getDbo('mod_cmse_products')
        ->select('prod_alias', 'prod_id', 'prod_gid')
        ->where('prod_alias', $filename)
        ->get()[0];

        if( $filename == $postval->alias ) {
            $posturl = menus()->select('id', 'url', 'src_id')->where([['src_id', $postval->catid],['type', 2]])->get()[0];
            parse_str(parse_url($posturl->url)['query'], $urlparts);

            $queryurl = 'component='.$urlparts['component'].'&view=post&category='.$urlparts['category'].'&post='.$postval->id.'-'.$path['filename'].'&menuid='.$urlparts['menuid'];
        }else

        // component is products
        if( $filename == $prodval->prod_alias ) {
            $prodgroup = getDbo('mod_cmse_products')->where('group_id', $prodval->prod_gid)->value('group_alias');
            $queryurl = 'component=products&view=productdetail&gid='.$prodval->prod_gid.'-'.$prodgroup.'&pid='.$prodval->prod_id.'-'.$prodval->prod_alias;
        }

    }


    $queryurl = html_entity_decode($queryurl);


    // get query elements
    $view       = getInput($queryurl, 'view');
    $category   = getInput($queryurl, 'category');
    $post       = getInput($queryurl, 'post');
    $menuid     = str_replace('-', '', (int)getInput($queryurl, 'menuid'));
    $listpage   = getInput($queryurl, 'listpage');
    $prodid     = getInput($queryurl, 'pid');
    $groupid    = getInput($queryurl, 'gid');
    $parent     = $match[0];

    // registered components
    $com_posts = ['post', 'category', 'categories'];
    $com_product = ['productdetail', 'productgroup', 'productgroups'];

    // the decider (roger)
    if( in_array($view, $com_product) ) {
        $component  = 'products';
    }else
    if( in_array($view, $com_posts) ) {
        $component  = 'posts';
    }

    $list = [$component, $view, $category, $post, $menuid, $listpage, $prodid, $groupid, $parent];

    return $list;
}


/* 
router which wraps URL out put in files
eg: <a href="<?php echo router($modlink.'&view=post&category='.$post->catid.'-'.$cat->alias.'&post='.$post->id.'-'.$post->alias.'&menuid='.$menuid); ?>">View Post</a>
*/

function router($url) 
{
    $parts = parse_url(ROOT_URL.$url);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $q);

    $component  = $q['component'];
    $view       = $q['view'];
    $category   = $q['category'];
    $post       = $q['post'];
    $menuid     = $q['menuid'];
    $prodgroup  = $q['gid'];
    $prodid     = $q['pid'];


    if( isset($component) ) 
    {
        if( $view == 'post' && isset($post) && !isset($category) && isset($menuid) ) {
            $num = (int)$post;
            $route = str_replace($num.'-', '', $post);
        }else
            // posts without menu id uses category alias in url
        if( $view == 'post' && isset($post) && isset($category) ) {
            $num = (int)$post;
            $nums = (int)$category;
            $route = str_replace($nums.'-', '', $category).'/'.str_replace($num.'-', '', $post);
        }else
        // posts category view
        if( $view == 'category' && isset($category) ) {
            $num = (int)$category;
            $route = str_replace($num.'-', '', $category);
        }else
        if( $view == 'categories' ) {
            $num = (int)$menuid;
            $route = str_replace($num.'-', '', $menuid);
        }else

        // product detail view
        if( $view == 'productdetail' && isset($prodgroup) && isset($prodid) ) {
            $route = preg_replace('#\d+\-#', '', strtolower($prodgroup)).'/'.preg_replace('#\d+\-#', '', $prodid);
        }else

        if( isset($view) && $view == 'productgroup' && isset($prodgroup) ) {
            $num = (int)$prodgroup;
            $route = str_replace($num.'-', '', $prodgroup);
        }else
        if( isset($view) && $view == 'productgroups' ) {
            $num = (int)$menuid;
            $route = str_replace($num.'-', '', $menuid);

            if( pathinfo(currenturl())['filename'] == 'cart' && !requestKey('a') ) {
                redirect(str_replace($num.'-', '', $menuid), 301);
            }
        }

    }else{
        // default urls
        $route = $url;
    }

    return $route;
}
```

What's bizarre is when I use Facebook's object debugger to scrape the pages, though the report 404, the og:image is returned and when I click "see what the scraper sees", the HTML code is correct! So the bot is seeing the right HTML yet reports "bad response code".

I tried adding the following condition to instruct the bots to use the given URL but it does not work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule .* [L]
```

This is the URL type which fails with 404 and sometimes 500, only when seen by bots http://websitedons.net/demo/whmcs/the-blog

But this URL returns 200 http://websitedons.net/demo/whmcs

How must the htaccess be written to deliver consistently good responses?

Comment: Are you sure it is the htaccess causing the 404's?

Comment: @JohnConde No. However since there are no php errors,  it seems logical to me that the bots are being instructed by the htaccess and therefore return a false positive. Please present any potential cause you see.

Comment: `wget -S http://websitedons.net/demo/whmcs/the-blog` gives `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` and exactly the same from my Firefox (which still displays the page). So it seems to always return 404, not only to bots. There is nothing in your PHP code that touches the return code.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Do you have any coding suggestion which could resolve this error? The core framework is WHMCS host billing system which is IonCube encrypted so I cannot define its redirection method therefore working in the dark.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek and JohnConde are you guys with-holding possible solutions or don't have any ideas for resolving the error?

Comment: There is nothing in what you have shown that can explain the 404 code.It comes from "elsewhere".You say also that you get 500 sometimes... in which case this is serious enough to be logged by the webserver so studying its logfiles should give hints on what is wrong. Also, usual dichotomy practices in troubleshooting apply: try to reduce your perimeter, like retest without htaccess, or with simplified PHP, etc. until you narrow down the culprit. Note also that my test with `wget` shows no `location` header in reply, hence no redirection happening... You can also increase Apache log verbosity.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks, I resolved the problem with a htaccess rewriterule. The site is now reporting 200 responses.

Comment: @Nadal Please post an "answer" detailing how you resolved this issue - as this may help future readers. (You can also later accept it.) I am certainly curious to know what "rewriterule" you used to "fix this"? TBH, I can't see how your `.htaccess` could be the cause of this issue? Which suggests that maybe there is a server issue? (Although your `.htaccess` file does seem overly complex for what it actually does and it is not without error. And it doesn't actually perform the _rewrite_ you say it does?)

Comment: @MrWhite I will certainly post the solution ASAP, time is a bit stressing at the moment. That htaccess is auto created by the WHMCS application. Thanks for acknowledging that it is unnecessarily complex as with much of the software. When I tell them, quite respectfully, that the coding is bloated, they get mad.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the error with a rewrite rule and a bit of php coding to change the error response method used by WHMCS, which is based of fixed values and if those are not defined in the array, an error is sent via Zend apiemitter

I added a condition and rule before all other rules

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* exrule.php [L]
```

which is placed in the host root or where WHMCS is installed, and the coding for the php

```
(new Zend\Diactoros\Response\SapiEmitter())->emit($statuscode);
```